# Help understanding simple voltage regulator output

Tags: voltage-regulator, diodes

[image]I made a small circuit using LTSpice and want to try to understand the output.
My input is a 1.4V sinewave with a +10V offset (Vin = 10V + 1.4V*sin(2*pi*f*t)). The Zener Diode has a Breakdown Voltage of 6.2V

1. I can see that the Zener Diode breaks down immidiately. Is that caused by the 10V offset ?
2. How can I calculate the peak of the output voltage ?

Comment: You need to know the peak current, the knee voltage (presumably 6.2V) and the slope resistance of the zener diode.

Comment: It does not matter how many ways you ask this question. You are still missing some vital information to get an answer to the puzzle. Either you need the diode characteristics, or, if we are to assume the diode is ideal, the load information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, the Zener breaks down because of the 10V offset. The sine wave is to allow you to measure the impedance of the Zener model at the test current.
2. From the datasheet you can usually find information that will help. Zx (dynamic impedance), for example, but it has to be specified at or near the operating current.  This particular type of Zener from Rohm is rather poorly specified- perhaps the model parameters were extracted from actual measurements, or perhaps they're not all that realistic.

Answer (score 1):

Any voltage above 6.2V will cause the Zener to break down.
Peak current will simply be (11.4 - 6.2)/100 = 52 mA

Answer (score 0):

Actually your voltage regulator works. 2,8Vpp input variation causes only 6mVpp variation in output. Not bad for a circuit this simple.

This regulator principle is not good, if you want to use the regulated voltage to supply some load which takes plenty of current and that current is not constant, but varies widely.

This principle of course works also in high current systems, but it wastes energy all the time. The zenerdiode sucks just as much as is needed to drop the voltage to about 6,2V when part of the resistor's current is taken by the possible load and the zenerdiode sucks the rest.